# Convert Bangla date to standard English date

Tags: php, date

I need to convert **Bangla Date** to **standard English date** format. My bangle date :

```
$banglaDate = '৩১ ডিসেম্বর, ২০১৪ ইং ১০:৫৭ মিঃ';
```

And I need to convert this bangle date to standard English date ( `2014-12-31 10:57` )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following step :

```
<?PHP
    $banglaDate = '৩১ ডিসেম্বর, ২০১৪ ইং ১০:৫৭ মিঃ';

    $search_array= array("১", "২", "৩", "৪", "৫", "৬", "৭", "৮", "৯", "০", "জানুয়ারী", "ফেব্রুয়ারী", "মার্চ", "এপ্রিল", "মে", "জুন", "জুলাই", "আগষ্ট", "সেপ্টেম্বার", "অক্টোবার", "নভেম্বার", "ডিসেম্বার", ":", ",");

    $replace_array= array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", ":", ","); 

    // convert all bangle char to English char 
    $en_number = str_replace($search_array, $replace_array, $banglaDate);   

    // remove unwanted char       
    $end_date =  preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9:\-]/', ' ', $en_number);

    // convert date
    $bangla_date = date("Y-m-d H:i ", strtotime($end_date));

   // output : 2014-12-31 10:57
?>
```

Comment: Oh, so it's not actually using the Bangla calendar, that's just the Gregorian date written in Bangla.  I thought this was a calendar-conversion problem, not a simple transliteration problem.